# How to generate random categorical data from existing ones to fill missing values - Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, data-presentation

I have a column with missing categorical data and I am trying to replace them by existing categorical variables from the same column.

I do not want to use the mode because I have too many missing data, it will skew the data and I would rather not drop the rows with missing data.

I think the ideal way would be to get the proportion of each variables for my column and then replace the missing proportionally by the existing categorical variables.

Example dataframe:

```
   ClientId    Apple_cat    Region    Price
0  21          cat_1        Reg_A     5
1  15          cat_2        Nan       6
2  6           Nan          Reg_B     7
3  91          cat_3        Reg_A     3
4  45          Nan          Reg_C     7
5  89          cat_2        Nan       6
```

Note: Ideally, I'd like to avoid hardcoding each category and region name.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What is your expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Expected output: fill missing data proportionally by existing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll your own function for a neat and vectorized method to solving this:

```
def na_randomfill(series):
    na_mask = pd.isnull(series)   # boolean mask for null values
    n_null = na_mask.sum()        # number of nulls in the Series
    
    if n_null == 0:
        return series             # if there are no nulls, no need to resample
    
    # Randomly sample the non-null values from our series
    #  only sample this Series as many times as we have nulls 
    fill_values = series[~na_mask].sample(n=n_null, replace=True, random_state=0)

    # This ensures our new values will replace NaNs in the correct locations
    fill_values.index = series.index[na_mask]
    
    return series.fillna(fill_values)
```

This solution works on 1 Series at time and can be called like so:

```
out = na_randomfill(df["Apple_cat"])

print(out)
0    cat_1
1    cat_2
2    cat_3
3    cat_3
4    cat_2
5    cat_2
Name: Apple_cat, dtype: object
```

Alternatively you can use apply to call it on each of your columns. Note that because of the `if` statement in our function, we do not need to specify null-containing columns in advance before calling `apply`:

```
out = df.apply(na_randomfill)

print(out)
   ClientId Apple_cat Region  Price
0        21     cat_1  Reg_A      5
1        15     cat_2  Reg_A      6
2         6     cat_3  Reg_B      7
3        91     cat_3  Reg_A      3
4        45     cat_2  Reg_C      7
5        89     cat_2  Reg_C      6
```

Comment: Actually for my dataframe with about 50'000 rows I get the following error message: 
`ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'`. Yet it does work on the sample data I posted, do you know how I may fix this issue?

Comment: I have used 'replace=True' it appears to be working, but I'm not sure what it really does

Comment: Ah, `replace=True` is the correct solution here, I thought that was the default option (apparently not). When you sample an array (say you have values `["a", "b", "c"]`) with `replace = True`, if we sample this array twice then we will sample from `["a", "b", "c"]` twice. Allowing us to potentially draw `"a"` twice, `"b"` twice, or `"c"` twice. If `replace=False` and we made 2 draws the item drawn on the first draw is removed from the list before sampling again. So if we draw `"a"` on our first draw, then our second draw is limited to `["b", "c"]`

Comment: Thanks! well explained

Answer (score 0):

The hard part of replacing NaN in a pandas Dataframe is that the fillna() method will replace all the nans with the same number, even if you put some kind of randomness in the call.

```
import random
df['Apple_cat'].applymap(lambda x: x if not np.isnan(x) else np.random.choice(random.choice(list(x.dropna(axis=0))))
```

This will replace the Nans with a random sample from the rest of th column.
Maybe you will need to replace np.nan by the other type of nan.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the missing values based on the probability distribution of the filled rows.

```
import numpy as np

df[‘<your_column_name>’] = df[‘<your_column_name>’].fillna(‘TBD’)
possible_values = df[‘<your_column_name>’].value_counts().to_dict()

possible_values.pop(‘TBD’)
total_items = sum(possible_values.keys())
possible_values = [(k,v) for k,v in possible_values.items()]
prob_dist = [i[1]/total_items for i in possible_values]

def fill_missing_values(item):
    if item != ‘TBD’:
        index = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(prob_dist), p=prob_dist)
        return possible_values[index]
    return item

df[‘<your_column_name>’] = df[‘<your_column_name>’].apply(lambda x: fill_missing_values(x))
```

Comment: Why do you use 'return' twice?

Comment: if the item is not TBD, i.e the already filled value you need to keep it as is.